# Python Eldoc fails when editing a remote file with a local shell open

Tags: python, eldoc

Problem: Eldoc constantly spews FileNotFoundErrors into the minibuffer when editing a remote python file if you have a local python shell  open.

To Recreate:

- `> emacs -Q`
- `M-x run-python`
- open a file on a remote server and move the point around
- minibuffer then periodically gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line  1, in <module>
  File "/home/path/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 905 in open
   file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory '/tmp/pyJduZe2'
```

That temp file  is being created on the remote server but then the local shell it seems is trying to open it. I  don't  want to just disable eldoc mode since I am otherwise trying to get it working with eglot mode with a remote lsp server (although that only works sometimes). Unfortunately this error isn't causes an actual emacs error so I can't use a debug trace to find out where it's being thrown. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce your problem with Emacs 27.2. With Emacs 28.1, this doesn't happen. Maybe time to upgrade?

Comment: Ah, didn't realize I was out of date. The perils of having to  use a mac for work.